# Piwik Administrator accounts not visible to each other

Tags: web-analytics, matomo, web-analytics-tools, openwebanalytics

Is it possible using one instance of Piwik to have multiple Administrator accounts which are not sharing particular websites among themselves and they are not visible to each other?

If so, then how to do it? If not, then maybe there's some other software I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set permissions to a website to "admin" level and assign different user to each set of websites. You don't have to set "superuser" permission.